# I have many divs i want to auto like content that have some specific hashtag? its actually liking tweets but not with that hashtag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm actually building an extension for auto liking and sharing tweets.
it likes and share tweets but not with hashtag in if condition. can you help me out?

let content = document.querySelectorAll(".r-kzbkwu");

[].forEach.call(content, function (h) {

```
// console.log(h);

if (h.textContent.includes("#letsconnect")) {

  let retweet = document.getElementsByClassName("r-bt1l66");

  let check = retweet[3].getAttribute("data-testid");

  //if already has not been liked then click like button
  // console.log(check);
  if (check != "unlike") {
    retweet[3].click();
  }
  let retweetCheck = retweet[2].getAttribute("data-testid");
  if (retweetCheck != "unretweet") {
    retweet[2].click();

    let dropdown = document.getElementById("layers");
    // console.log(dropdown);
    // reach to retweet dropdown
    let reqDev =
      dropdown.children["1"].children["0"].children["0"].children["0"]
        .children[1].children["2"].children["0"];
    let attt = reqDev.getAttribute("data-testid");
    // if already has not been retweeted then click button
    // console.log(attt);
    if (attt != "unretweetConfirm") {
      reqDev.click();
    }
    
  }
}
```

});

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want my extension to like tweet with hashtag #letsconnect but it likes random tweet. it does not follow if condition in code. is it may be i dont know how to check if content inside child div contain hashtag or not? I have added the code above with if condition.